# Hierarchical query, use parent values for missing children values

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have the following data set:

```
id  parentId    entityId    isAllowed
45  NULL        1           0
46  45          2           1
46  45          3           1
47  46          3           0
47  46          4           0
```

For each id, I want to fetch values for all entities, whether it's direct or inherited. So for each entity:

- If a child has a direct value, use it.
- If a child has no direct value, it should use its parent's value (if exists).
- If a child and its parent have no value, don't show that.

The 'isAllowed' value should be of the latest child.

The result should be something like this:

```
id  entityId    isAllowed
45  1           0
46  1           0
47  1           0
46  2           1
47  2           1
46  3           1
47  3           0
47  4           0
```

Note that for entity 1, id's 45-47 have the same value (inherited for 46-47). For entity 3, 45 has no value (because there's no direct value and no inherited value), while 46 and 47 both have their direct value.

I managed to implement the 'isAllowed' part using the following query:

```
WITH p AS (
 SELECT id, 
        parentId, 
        entityId,
        isAllowed
    FROM t1
    WHERE parentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t1.id,
           t1.parentId,
           t1.entityId,
           COALESCE(t1.isAllowed, p.isAllowed)
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN p ON p.id = t1.parentId)

SELECT * FROM p
```

Any idea how to query that? Thanks!

Comment: without using T-SQL?! what do you want to do it with then?!

Comment: So you want to use a different language? Like... Python, C#, R, C++, JS, etc... there's probably 100 ways to do this, even with other flavors of SQL that aren't T-SQL. You need to be more specific.

Comment: what you mean `if it does not have an explicit value` ?? I see everyone has value `0 / 1`

Comment: @Tanner I'm coming from Oracle so I probably used the wrong terminology. I meant using plain SQL over the the procedural language. If it isn't possible, then a T-SQL solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Some don't have values at all. For example, entities 1-2 for id 47.

Comment: Then for start you need a separated table so we can tell which entities are missing, How I know there is an entities 25 somewhere else. Or because Id 45 doesnt have entities 2 or 3 in your example

Comment: So you mean using ISO compliant SQL only (which may or may not be supported by SQL Server, and is most definitely not supported on every platform)?.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's clear in the example. Id 47 should have values for 1-4 but has explicit values for 3-4 only. 46 should have values for 1-3 but has explicit values for 2-3.

Comment: Maybe is clear for you. There is nothing in your question telling me that. Explain your logic otherwise is too broad to answer.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The idea is that if a child has no explicit value, it should use its parent's value, for each entity, so if a parent has a value for some entity, its children should also have them. That's demonstrated in the expected output example (compared to the existing data set). I hope that it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, Is clear now. But that should be part of the question. Otherwise other people will miss that information unless they read all the comments. And you could explain it with examples to make it clear.

Comment: @Larnu No. As I said, I'm coming from Oracle where it's clear what is plain SQL and what is PL/SQL. Seems that it's different in SQL Server, so I'd be happy for any possible solution.